# Issue on save and update the same item restangular

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I have a problem when I create an item and saved, is created normally, but the problem is this , if I click again on SAVE , you create a new item and not done in this update even created item.

I'm using RESTangular and mongodb , yet could not find a solution to this because the server does not return given me any . I've tried to take a copy of item , but as the ID is equal to the server rejects .

```
$scope.section = $stateParams.section;

// create new object item
$scope.item = ApiRestangular.one($scope.section);


$scope.addItem = function(){
    $scope.item.save().then(function(){
             toast.msgToast($scope.section + ' ...item criado!');
    }, function(err){
        toast.msgToast($scope.section + ' ...ocorreu um erro ao criar o item!');
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Put or Post operations (Update or Save) should return the item that was saved. Replace `$scope.item` with the returned value and it should update the second time around. If not, explicitly call `.post` or `.put`

```
$scope.addItem = function(){
    $scope.item.save().then(function(response){
        $scope.item = response.data;
        toast.msgToast($scope.section + ' ...item criado!');
    }, function(err){
        toast.msgToast($scope.section + ' ...ocorreu um erro ao criar o item!');
    });
};
```

Also, the object you first save typically doesn't have an ID which is needed to update it. The returned value should have this ID.

Comment: Hi, thx for response, but same error.. Error: response is undefined, in post, save and put. in put..error 409 Conflict

Comment: May need to use Restangular.restangularizeElement instead of ApiRestangular.one to make a restangular element out of $scope.section. If not, then then it sounds like the server is having issues with what you are trying to save.

Comment: I @Mike Restangular.restangularizeElement.one is not a function, my scope: $scope.item = Restangular.restangularizeElement.one($scope.section);